# run an Excel Macro from Python (but an Excel process stays in memory)

Tags: python, excel, win32com

with the following python method, I make a call to an Excel macro. I was happy when I got that to work, however I was wondering everytime I was executing this I could see a Windows temporary/lock file of the same name as the .XLA I was using the Macro from.

```
class XlaMakeUnmake:

    __configFile = 'xla_svn.cfg'
    __vbaTools = 'makeProtected.xla'
    __entries = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__readConfig()

    def __newDirs(self, dir):
        try:
            os.makedirs(dir)
        except OSError, e:
            if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise 

    ### WILL ONLY WORK FOR UNPROTECTED
    '''
    filePath: path of XLA to unmake
    outputDir: folder in which the lightweight xla and its components will be pushed to
    '''
    def unmake(self, filePath, outputDir):
        xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        xl.Visible = 0
        self.__newDirs(outputDir)
        xl.Application.Run("'" + os.getcwd() + os.sep + self.__vbaTools +   "'!Unmake", filePath, outputDir)
```

When I open the task manager, I can see that an Excel process is still running... How to kill it but in a clean fashion when the job is done ? Is `xl.Application.Run` launching an asynchronous call to the Macro ? In which case it might be tricky...

Thanks guys !! ;)

Comment: You need to release the instance of the Excel application. Not sure how to do that in Python; in VB, you'd set `xl = Nothing`, in Delphi you'd set `xl := nil;`, if that helps.

Comment: I tried to do a "xl = None", but not effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Python, but you need to use:

```
xl.Quit
```

Comment: I tried that after "xl.Application.Run", python doesnt complain, but no effect.

Comment: Ahhh, stupid me, I had to do xl.Quit(), otherwise python takes that as a new attribute of the object. It works !